# Pesquisa por campos

Tags: php

Oi, eu fiz uma pagina que pesquisa os produtos cadastrados e depois aparece os resultados na pagina resultados.php.

Gostaria que nessa mesma página resultados.php depois pudesse fazer uma consulta mais exata como por preço menor aparecer primeiro, ter a opção de escolher o produto novo ou usado, apareçer pessoa fisica ou juridica.

Postei meu codigo no pastebin: http://pastebin.com/PVkBvA9R

```
<?php include 'header.php'; ?>

<header class="docs-top">
    <div class="container docs-header">
   Todos os resultados
 </div>
</header>
<section>
  <div class="container">

    <?php 
    require 'conexao.php';

    $produto = $_POST['produto'];
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM usuario where produto LIKE '%".$produto."%' ");

    // SELECT preco FROM usuario ORDER BY preco ASC

    $row = mysql_num_rows($sql);
    if ($row > 0) {
      while ($linha = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
        $produto = $linha['produto'];
        $bairro = $linha['bairro'];
        $preco = $linha['preco'];
        $telefone = $linha['telefone'];
        $nome = $linha['nome'];
        $estado = $linha['estado'];
      }
    } else {
      echo "Nenhum resultado encontrado";
    }
    ?>


    <div class="well recomentadion clearfix">
      <h1>Pesquisar</h1>
      <form action="" method="POST">     
        <fieldset>
          <div class="form-group col-md-3">
            <label class="" for="advertisement">Título do Anúncio </label>                
            <div class="control mr-30">
              <input type="text" id="title" name="title" class="form-control" value="" placeholder="Título" data-original-title="" title="">
            </div>
          </div>                  

          <div class="form-group col-md-3">
            <label class="" for="advertisement">Novo/Usado</label>                
            <div class="control mr-30">
              <select class="form-control">                               
                <option>Novo</option>
                <option>Usado</option>
              </select> 
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group col-md-3">
            <label class="" for="advertisement">Empresa/P. fisica</label>                
            <div class="control mr-30">
             <select class="form-control">
              <option>Todos</option>
              <option>Empresa</option>
              <option>Pessoa fisica</option>
            </select> 
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group col-md-3">
          <label class="" for="advertisement">Ordernar por Preço</label>                
          <div class="control mr-30">
            <select class="form-control">
              <option>Menor preço</option>
              <option>Maior preço</option>                               
            </select>  
          </div>
        </div>  

        <div class="clear"></div> 
        <input type="submit" style="margin-top:20px;" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" value="Pesquisar"> 
      </fieldset>
    </form>
  </div>

  <!-- produto -->

  <div class="bs-docs-example">
    <table class="table table-bordered">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td align="center">:<img src="http://wcloudstatic.s3.amazonaws.com/img/no_image.jpeg" width="150" height="150" /></td>                 
          <td><?php echo ".$produto"; ?> <br><br> <?php echo ".$bairro"; ?> - <?php echo ".$estado"; ?><br> <?php echo ".$nome"; ?> - <?php echo ".$telefone"; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo ".$preco"; ?></td>
        </tr>          
      </tbody>
    </table>    
  </div>

  <!-- /produto -->

</div>

</section>

<?php include 'footer.php'; ?>
```

Comment: Sempre poste o código ou trecho do código que você está com dúvida aqui, para facilitar a análise dos colegas do site.

Comment: Tá, você disse seu objetivo, mas não disse o que está te impedindo ou qual o problema/dificuldade. Pelo que vi, seu código deve estar exibindo apenas o último registro e não a lista toda.

Answer (score 0):

Você quer pegar o produto na tabela usuário? Tem que modelar corretamente o banco para melhor implementar as querys.

Você fez o correto na estrutura de query para exibir o produto e não fez com o preco. Só faltou um pouco de atenção.

Seguindo seu exemplo, vou colocar tudo numa query.

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM usuario where produto LIKE '%".$produto."%' order by preco asc");

$row = mysql_num_rows($sql);
if ($row > 0) {

  while ($linha = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
    $produto = $linha['produto'];
    $bairro = $linha['bairro'];
    $preco = $linha['preco'];
    $telefone = $linha['telefone'];
    $nome = $linha['nome'];
    $estado = $linha['estado'];
  }

} else {
  echo "Nenhum resultado encontrado";
}
?>
```

Ou você pode usar paginator para escolher o modo de exibição, por preco, produto, pessoa física ou jurídica, etc.

Recomendo estudar as relações de tabelas e suas chaves.

Comment: Mas esse preço deveria só aparecer depois quando o usuario usasse o select para selecionar melhor a pesquisa, entende?

Assim como os outros campos

Comment: Então ainda não entendi.

O select na query vai retornar tudo que estiver na tabela Usuario. Você vai tratar os dados como quiser. Na verdade, estarão ordenados de forma crescente.

Só não entendi quando você diz que mostrará o preço quando o usuário selecionar. Neste caso, só exibirá o preco quando o usuário escolher um produto? Para facilitar,  dê um exemplo com dados.